# How to add two columns based on header names and paste results in a third row based on header name?

Tags: linux, unix, awk

How can I add 2 columns (test 1 and test 2) and print the result in a fourth column based on column header names? (CSV file)- comma demilited file

Input:

```
test1 test2 test3 test4
1 2 x 
2 4 Y
```

Output:

```
test1 test2 test3 test4
1 2 x 3
2 4 Y 6
```

I tried the below which works but I want it to be based on the column headers and not positions.

```
awk -F, '{$3=$1+$2;} {print $1,$2,$3}' OFS=, testing.csv

awk -F, '{$3=$1+$2;} {print $1,$2,$3}' OFS=, testing.csv
```

Input:

```
test1 test2 test3 test4
1 2 x 
2 4 Y
```

Output:

```
test1 test2 test3 test4 
1 2 x 3
2 4 Y 6
```

Comment: And if your input and output are comma-separated then show THAT in your example, don't show space-separated instead of your real format.

Comment: @EdMorton I am sorry about the confusion. I have now mentioned it that its a csv file - comma delimited.

Comment: Don't just mention it - show it. Your example needs to be truly representative of your real data. If your real data is comma separated then show an example that's comma separated, not an example that's space separated. If your real data doesn't have blank lines between data lines, then don't show blank lines between the data lines in your example.

Comment: @EdMorton to use an approach *"based on the column headers"* -- how are we supposed to get the particular names of the *"column headers"* to manipulate? It seems we are boiling this all down to fields regardless of the header names to arrive at the sum in the last field. I don't see how the header names are relevant unless you are passing that information into the `awk` script at some point? Am I missing something obvious there?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The column header names are the values of the fields on the first line of input. This application is something I deal with frequently where I have to get data out of CSVs generated from Excel spreadsheets, for example, and all of the data I care about is present but in CSV 1 the "address", say, is in column 4 while in CSV 2 the "address" just happens to be in column 7 instead. So I write my scripts to create an array `f[]` mapping names to values when the first line of each CSV is read and then I can just use `$(f["address"])` from then on.

Comment: I get that part. The part I don't get is how are we responding to any difference in the names? The header could be `monkey,banana,fruit,pie` and we would still be summing fields 1 & 2 to use as field 4 for every record other than the first. Now if we were passing in `pie = monkey +  banana` at some point, the column heading would be relevant. But if we are just summing the first two as the final for every `FNR > 1` -- I'm having trouble understanding how the column header is relevant. This is more for @sagarmanhas I guess.

Comment: That's not the task at hand though - it's to be able to write `pie = monkey + banana` (literally `$(f["pie"]) = $(f["monkey"]) + $(f["banana"])` with the approach I'm advocating) and have the script work even if the input is rearranged such that now `pie` is the 1st instead of 4th column, and `monkey` is the 3rd, etc.

Comment: OK, so your interpretation is just grab the column header field names and use those as a numeric reference to do the same thing, but it is by using the name as the numeric reference that is the important point here. If that is the point, then yep, you nailed it. I was simply avoiding creating the references that `test1 = 1, test2 = 2, etc..` and using the numbers themselves. I took that approach based on the complete lack of any correlation between the header row names and anything else that takes place later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to deal with this is to create an array that maps the column header strings (i.e. the field names) to the field numbers when reading the header line and then just access the fields by their names from then on:

```
$ awk '
    NR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) f[$i]=i }
    NR>1 { $(f["test4"]) = $(f["test1"]) + $(f["test2"]) }
1' file
test1 test2 test3 test4
1 2 x 3
2 4 Y 6
```

I assumed above that you don't really have blank lines between data lines in your input. Trivially handled if you do.

If your input/output is really CSV then just create a BEGIN section declaring that:

```
$ cat file
test1,test2,test3,test4
1,2,x,
2,4,Y

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) f[$i]=i} NR>1{$(f["test4"]) = $(f["test1"]) + $(f["test2"])} 1' file
test1,test2,test3,test4
1,2,x,3
2,4,Y,6
```

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you. I am relatively very new to unix and thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome. Please do still fix the example in your question to make it more useful to the next person looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sample input:

```
cat inputfile
test1 test2 test3 test4
1 2 x
2 4 Y
```

Here, from the first line read header and get the column number of test1 and test2 and store it into variables `t1` and `t2` and then reassign the `$4` with itself and sum of column pointed by `t1` and `t2` .

```
awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="test1") t1=i; else if($i=="test2") t2=i} NR>1{$4=$4 FS $t1+$t2} {print }' inputfile
test1 test2 test3 test4
1 2 x  3
2 4 Y  6
```

In case you have blank lines in your input file and want to preserve them then use `NF` as non-zero as check like `NR>1&& NF{$4=$4 FS $t1+$t2}`.

Comment: Hi @EdMorton I would like to print all the columns but currently only one column is getting printed. Also, is it possible to have column header for $4 instead of $4